# Can you create an oft file in anything other than Outlook?

Tags: file, outlook

Can you create an oft file in anything other than Outlook?

Answer (score 2):

A .oft file has the same format as .MSG, so you can use OpenIMsgOnIStg to access this type of file via MAPI. Here’s a good starting place for working with that stuff: http://blogs.msdn.com/stephen_griffin/archive/2006/05/25/unicode-msg-files.aspx

See also here:
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/CMapiEx.aspx?msg=3220011

Comment: These are just programmatically calling into Outlook, though.

Comment: Are you sure? The guy who wrote the CodeProject article says that his NetMAPI class is a thin layer above the Win32 DLL, MAPIEx.dll

Comment: See also http://coolthingoftheday.blogspot.com/2005/09/vbnet-dll-wrapper-for-c-mapiex.html